# Javascript round with a zero at the end (fixed number of decimals)

Tags: javascript, numbers, rounding

Im using javascript `round` to round the numbers. But when the value is `$106.70` the output shows only `$106.7` and its missing the last `0`. How can I add a zero for numbers ending with a zero or is there any easier way than using if else to check this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`.toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method:

```
var n = 106.72; console.log(n.toFixed(2)); //=> '106.72'
var n = 106.70; console.log(n.toFixed(2)); //=> '106.70'
var n = 106.7; console.log(n.toFixed(2)); //=> '106.70'
var n = 106; console.log(n.toFixed(2)); //=> '106.00'
```

And it rounds:

```
var n = 106.76; console.log(n.toFixed(1)); //=> '106.8'
```

Comment: How can the last one give 106.70? :)